# Reduce Initial Connection & TTFB Time

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Similar Question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539784/how-to-reduce-the-time-for-the-first-byte-on-my-website)

Website: [Cleanfiles PPD Network](http://cleanfiles.net/)

```
Raw Server Link (Skip DNS): http://173.247.246.58/
```

Waterfall view (Webpage Test):
[image: Waterfall]

I recently moved to a new server. **All PHP scripts and resources stayed exactly the same**. The new server is an [Inmotion Elite Dedicated Server](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/dedicated_servers/features.html).

Average server load:

```
Server load 1.25 (8 CPUs)   
Memory Used 14.14% (1,137,916 of 8,048,804) 
Swap Used   0% (0 of 4,095,992)
```

As a network owner, having a quick and nifty site is a top priority. I can't afford to have 2-4 seconds of random waiting time for my members when navigating through-out pages. The old server never did this, it loaded fine.

Since the server load appears to be fine and the PHP scripts are the same, I want to assume it is something with some Apache settings or something like that. I really cannot tell. I tried running the two scripts listed in the Top Answer of the question posted above, but both had long wait times...

I talked to the hosting company but they didn't really know what was going on. Any help with this issue or tests that I can do would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: "initial connection" means waiting for the server to accept a connection - a typical cause for delay is the server is hitting the max-clients limit (apache configuration) and waiting for an existing request to finish before being able to process the current request. If that waterfall is in seconds, it's clear that most of the content is served via PHP - which would greatly increase the probability of hitting the max-client limit. If that's the case, an obvious first step is to serve static files, statically. Showing the apache config, and checking apache logs would confirm what's happening.

Comment: incidentally I see the domain in the question has very different results now, so there's no real need for others to guess what the cause is. It would be useful to take what you've identified, how and what changes made and post it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most effective solution is to use a CDN with native HTML caching capabilities (static and dynamic). TTFB relies on your ability to quickly process the HTML on the origin server, you can skip processing time altogether by serving a fresh cached copy from CDN.

I wrote a post about it recently, which looks into TTFB delay factors and average load time of different resources (based on data gathered across 1B sessions). You may find it useful: http://www.incapsula.com/the-incapsula-blog/item/809-using-cdn-to-improve-seo-and-ttfb

Comment: *If* this answers the question it's only doing so indirectly; while using a cdn would almost certainly have a (positive) effect it would do so mostly by preventing requests for static files from hogging apache, and therefore causing the delay indicated in the question for dynamic content.

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I say in my post. Basically, with bare bone CDNs you`ll probably loose more than you gain (loosely depending on dynamic/static ratio) However, I also describe a behavior learning tech that allows caching of dynamic files, with 90% of HTML content coming from CDN, TTFB is drastically improved.

Comment: I don't think you've understood my comment. Would you mind quoting any part of your post which addresses the following scenario: the webserver is setup to handle at most 2 requests in parallel - the 3rd request received in parallel must wait for one of the first two to finish before it will even start to be handled? This is the scenario typically responsible for such exaggerated response times (for static files also) as shown in the question. Notice that I don't mention "cdn" anywhere as while it might form part of a solution, it's not part of the question (or an answer to "why").

Comment: Sorry, I must disagree. Even in this specific scenario, you`ll be better of with a CDN which will assist with parallel processing. Yes, all 3 requests may reach an un-cacheable object, making CDN irrelevant. However, statistically speaking, if you have 40%-50% of static content (typical use case) and cache another 20%-25% via intelligent caching huristics (another typical use case) you just improved your chances for better parallel processing, simply by splitting the load a.) between CDN and origin b.) between multiple CDN locations.