# How to speed up my website for search engine?

Tags: php, performance, cakephp, search

I have a problem with showing results in search engines. It takes 8 seconds to search results to show. It is very long and does not make sense.

Is there a way to get a small part of the results displayed immediately (eg. displaying pages 1 and 2 separately), and the rest a few seconds later?

This is my code:

---

```
public function index($destination_main_id=null,$accommod_main_id=null,$search_period_code=null,$total_person=null,$pageNum=null, $order=null, $range_days=null){

//post podaci filtriranja
//print_r($_POST['filter']);
if(!empty($_POST['filter'])){
$this->set('ajax_load',1);
}else{
$this->set('ajax_load',0);
}

//inicijacija varijabli
if(!empty($_POST['radio1'])){
$this->request->data['SearchEngine']['accommod_main_id']=$_POST['radio1'];
}

if($order==''){
$order='asc';
}

if($range_days==''){
$range_days=0;
}

//search period
if(!$search_period_code){
$search_period=$this->Calendar->getDatesBetweenDates($this->request->data['SearchEngine']['arrival'], $this->request->data['SearchEngine']['departure']);
$search_period_code = base64_encode(serialize($search_period));
}else{
$search_period = @unserialize(base64_decode($search_period_code));
}
$count_search_period=count($search_period);

//destination
if(!empty($this->request->data['SearchEngine']['destination_main_id'])){
$destination_main_id=$this->request->data['SearchEngine']['destination_main_id'];
}

//accommodation type
if(!empty($this->request->data['SearchEngine']['accommod_main_id'])){
$accommod_main_id=$this->request->data['SearchEngine']['accommod_main_id'];
}

//person calculation
if(!empty($this->request->data['SearchEngine']['adults']) OR !empty($this->request->data['SearchEngine']['children1']) OR !empty($this->request->data['SearchEngine']['children2']) OR !empty($this->request->data['SearchEngine']['baby']) ){
if($this->request->data['SearchEngine']['baby']>=3){
$total_baby=round($this->request->data['SearchEngine']['baby']/3);
}else{
$total_baby=0;
}
$total_person=$this->request->data['SearchEngine']['adults']+$this->request->data['SearchEngine']['children1']+$this->request->data['SearchEngine']['children2']+$total_baby;
}

//+/- radio raspon
if(!empty($this->request->data['SearchEngine']['days'])){
$range_days=$this->request->data['SearchEngine']['days'];
}

//display accommodation units 
if(!empty($_POST['filter']))
{
$AccommodUnits=$this->AccommodUnit->getAllFilterUnits($total_person,$destination_main_id,$_POST['filter'],$this->lang);
}else{
$AccommodUnits=$this->AccommodUnit->getAllUnits($total_person,$destination_main_id,$this->lang);
} 

//display accommodation objects 
$AccommodObjectIds1=array();
$AccommodMainAccommodObjects=$this->AccommodMainAccommodObject->find('all',array('conditions' => array('AccommodMainAccommodObject.accommod_main_id' => $accommod_main_id),'order' => array('AccommodMainAccommodObject.accommod_object_id')));
foreach($AccommodMainAccommodObjects as $current1){ 
$this->AccommodObject->locale = $this->lang; 
$this->AccommodObject->recursive = -1;
$AccommodObject=$this->AccommodObject->find('first',array('conditions' => array('AccommodObject.id' => $current1['AccommodMainAccommodObject']['accommod_object_id'],'AccommodObject.active' => '1')));
if(!empty($AccommodObject['AccommodObject']['id'])){
$AccommodObjectIds1[]=$AccommodObject['AccommodObject']['id'];
}
}

//filtriranje by objects
$AccommodObjectIds3=array();
if( !empty($_POST['filter']['benefit']) ){
foreach($AccommodObjectIds1 as $current10){
$AccommodObject=$this->AccommodObject->getFilterObject($current10,$_POST['filter'],$this->lang);
if(!empty($AccommodObject)){
$AccommodObjectIds3[]=$AccommodObject['AccommodObject']['id'];
}
}
}else{
$AccommodObjectIds3=$AccommodObjectIds1;
}

//filtering by plyce
$AccommodObjectIds2=array();
if(!empty($_POST['filter']['place']))
{
$AccommodObjectDestinationArounds=$this->AccommodObjectDestinationAround->find('all',array('conditions' => array('AccommodObjectDestinationAround.destination_around_id' => $_POST['filter']['place']),'order' => array('AccommodObjectDestinationAround.accommod_object_id')));
foreach($AccommodObjectDestinationArounds as $current8){
$AccommodObjectIds2[]=$current8['AccommodObjectDestinationAround']['accommod_object_id'];
}
}

$AccommodObjectIdsFinale=array();
if(!empty($AccommodObjectIds2)){
foreach($AccommodObjectIds2 as $current9){
if(in_array($current9, $AccommodObjectIds3)) {
$AccommodObjectIdsFinale[]=$current9;
}
}
}else{
$AccommodObjectIdsFinale=$AccommodObjectIds3;
}

$arrival1=date('d.m.Y.',strtotime($search_period[0]));
$departure1=date('d.m.Y.',strtotime($search_period[count($search_period)-1]));

$arrival2=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($search_period[0]));
$departure2=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($search_period[count($search_period)-1]));

$AccommodUnitCounts=array();
$i=0;
foreach($AccommodUnits as $current2){
if(in_array($current2['AccommodUnit']['accommod_object_id'], $AccommodObjectIdsFinale)) {
$AccommodUnitCounts[$i]=$current2;
$AccommodUnitCounts[$i]['AccommodUnit']['arrival']=$arrival1;
$AccommodUnitCounts[$i]['AccommodUnit']['departure']=$departure1;
}
$i++;
}

$this->set('destination_main_id', $destination_main_id);
$this->set('accommod_main_id', $accommod_main_id);
$this->set('search_period_code', $search_period_code);
$this->set('total_person', $total_person);
$this->set('order',$order);
$this->set('range_days',$range_days);
$this->set('arrival',$arrival1);
$this->set('departure',$departure1);

//danas i tekuća godina
$today=date("Y-m-d");
$year=date("Y");


///////////////definition of free units (booking)
$SearchUnits=array();
$SearchUnitsIDs=array();
if(!empty($AccommodUnitCounts)){
$i=0;
foreach($AccommodUnitCounts as $current3){
//booking
$this->AccommodUnitBooking->locale = $this->lang;
$this->AccommodUnitBooking->recursive = -1;
$AccommodUnitBooking=$this->AccommodUnitBooking->find('first',array('conditions' => array('AccommodUnitBooking.accommod_unit_id' => $current3['AccommodUnit']['id'])));
if(!empty($AccommodUnitBooking)){
$this->AccommodUnitTablebooking->locale = $this->lang;
$this->AccommodUnitTablebooking->recursive = -1;
$AccommodUnitTablebookings=$this->AccommodUnitTablebooking->find('all',array('conditions' => array('AccommodUnitTablebooking.accommod_unit_id' => $current3['AccommodUnit']['id'], 'AccommodUnitTablebooking.accommod_unit_booking_id' => $AccommodUnitBooking['AccommodUnitBooking']['id'],'AccommodUnitTablebooking.booking' => $search_period ),'order' => array('AccommodUnitTablebooking.booking' => 'asc')));
if(!empty($AccommodUnitTablebookings)){
unset($current3);
}else{
$SearchUnits[]=$current3;
$SearchUnitsIDs[]=$current3['AccommodUnit']['id'];
}
}else{
$SearchUnits[]=$current3;
$SearchUnitsIDs[]=$current3['AccommodUnit']['id'];
}
$i++;
}
}


///////////////price calculation
if(!empty($SearchUnits)){
$i=0;
foreach($SearchUnits as $current6){
$booking_interval=count($this->Calendar->getDatesBetweenDates($arrival2, $departure2))-1;
$booking_interval_dates=array_slice($this->Calendar->getDatesBetweenDates($arrival2, $departure2),0,-1);
$accommod_booking=0;
if(!empty($current6['AccommodUnit']['fl_minute_start']) AND !empty($current6['AccommodUnit']['fl_minute_end']) AND !empty($current6['AccommodUnit']['fl_minute_price']) AND $current6['AccommodUnit']['fl_minute_start']==$arrival2 AND $current6['AccommodUnit']['fl_minute_end']==$departure2 ){ //LAST/FIRST MINUTE CIJENA
$accommod_booking=$current6['AccommodUnit']['fl_minute_price'];
$total=$accommod_booking*$booking_interval;
}else{
$this->AccommodUnitPrice->locale = $this->lang; 
$this->AccommodUnitPrice->recursive = -1;
$AccommodUnitPrice=$this->AccommodUnitPrice->find('first',array('conditions' => array('AccommodUnitPrice.accommod_unit_id' => $current6['AccommodUnit']['id'])));
$period=array();
$total=0;
foreach($booking_interval_dates as $interval_date){
for($j=1; $j<=7; $j++){
if(!empty($AccommodUnitPrice['AccommodUnitPrice']['period'.$j])){
$period[$j]=$AccommodUnitPrice['AccommodUnitPrice']['period'.$j];
$date[$j]=split('[/.-]', $period[$j]);
$date_start[$j]=$year.'-'.$date[$j][1].'-'.$date[$j][0];
$date_end[$j]=$year.'-'.$date[$j][4].'-'.$date[$j][3];
if($date_start[$j]<=$interval_date AND $date_end[$j]>=$interval_date){//ako interval rezervacije pada u razdoblje cjenika
$this->AccommodUnitTableprice->locale = $this->lang; 
$this->AccommodUnitTableprice->recursive = -1;
$AccommodUnitTableprice=$this->AccommodUnitTableprice->find('first',array('conditions' => array('AccommodUnitTableprice.accommod_unit_id' => $current6['AccommodUnit']['id'],'AccommodUnitTableprice.accommod_unit_price_id' => $AccommodUnitPrice['AccommodUnitPrice']['id'],'AccommodUnitTableprice.person_no' => $total_person,'AccommodUnitTableprice.day_no <=' => $booking_interval),'order' => array('AccommodUnitTableprice.person_no' => 'asc') ));
if(empty($AccommodUnitTableprice)){
$AccommodUnitTableprice=$this->AccommodUnitTableprice->find('first',array('conditions' => array('AccommodUnitTableprice.accommod_unit_id' => $current6['AccommodUnit']['id'],'AccommodUnitTableprice.accommod_unit_price_id' => $AccommodUnitPrice['AccommodUnitPrice']['id'],'AccommodUnitTableprice.day_no <=' => $booking_interval),'order' => array('AccommodUnitTableprice.person_no' => 'asc') ));
}

if(!empty($AccommodUnitTableprice)){
$accommod_booking=$AccommodUnitTableprice['AccommodUnitTableprice']['price'.$j];
$total=$total+$accommod_booking;
}
}
}
}
}
}
//destination
$this->DestinationMain->locale = $this->lang; 
$this->DestinationMain->recursive = -1;
$DestinationMain=$this->DestinationMain->find('first',array('conditions' => array('DestinationMain.id' => $current6['AccommodUnit']['destination_main_id'],'DestinationMain.active' => '1')));
$SearchUnits[$i]['DestinationMain']=$DestinationMain['DestinationMain'];
//accommodation object   
$this->AccommodObject->locale = $this->lang; 
$this->AccommodObject->recursive = -1;
$AccommodObject=$this->AccommodObject->find('first',array('conditions' => array('AccommodObject.id' => $current6['AccommodUnit']['accommod_object_id'],'AccommodObject.active' => '1')));
$SearchUnits[$i]['AccommodObject']=$AccommodObject['AccommodObject'];
//url-ovi kod tražilice za smještajnu jedinicu
$SearchUnits[$i]['AccommodUnit']['arrival_url']=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($current6['AccommodUnit']['arrival']));
$SearchUnits[$i]['AccommodUnit']['departure_url']=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($current6['AccommodUnit']['departure'])); 
//kalkulacija
if(!empty($AccommodObject['AccommodObject']['info_cleaning']) AND !empty($AccommodObject['AccommodObject']['supplement_cleaning'])){
$SearchUnits[$i]['AccommodUnit']['total_price']=$total+$AccommodObject['AccommodObject']['supplement_cleaning'];
}else{
$SearchUnits[$i]['AccommodUnit']['total_price']=$total;
}

$i++;
}
}

////filtriranje po cijeni
$max_value=800; //max price
if(!empty($_POST['filter']['price1']) OR (!empty($_POST['filter']['price2']) AND !empty($_POST['filter']['price2'])!=$max_value)){
$i=0;
$FilterPriceUnits=array();
foreach($SearchUnits as $current11){
if($current11['AccommodUnit']['total_price']>$_POST['filter']['price1'] AND $current11['AccommodUnit']['total_price']<=$_POST['filter']['price2'] ){
$FilterPriceUnits[]=$current11;
}
$i++;
}
$SearchUnits=array();
$SearchUnits=$FilterPriceUnits;
}

//pageing
$limit=15;

if($pageNum=='' OR !is_numeric($pageNum)){
$pageNum=1;
}

$nOfItems=count($SearchUnits);
$pages=$this->Pagination->makePagination($nOfItems, $pageNum, $limit,2, 2, '...');

$this->set('pages',$pages);
$this->set('pageNum',$pageNum);

$SearchUnitFinales = Set::sort($SearchUnits, '{n}.AccommodUnit.total_price', $order); 
$offset=($pageNum-1)*$limit;
$SearchUnitSlices = array_slice($SearchUnitFinales, $offset, $limit);
$this->set('accommod_unit_slices', $SearchUnitSlices);

}
```

Comment: Show source code of how you perform your search.

Comment: FWIW the above code looks nothing like good or even average CakePHP code. Maybe if it were indented I could at least read it (hint).

Answer (score 0):

Since your tag says **php** I would suggest looking into `memcached`. Also you would need to have pagination and load data only on page change, here is an example:

```
 //user clicked page number, 1,2,3 etc...
 $currentPage = isset($_POST['page']) ? (int)$_POST['page'] : 1; 

 // get 25 rows per page
 $startLimit  = ($currentPage-1) * 25; 
 $endLimit    = $startLimit + 25;
```

then you can use these limits in your query to grab only 25 records per page. Also I would use cache so everytime you change page does not have to execute query.

Comment: I suggest not making wild guesses/suggestions to questions before there's a question to answer. -1.

Comment: @AD7six well i am not guessing I am answering OP's question `Is there a way to get a small part of the results displayed immediately`.

Comment: The question is tagged CakePHP which means, amongst other things, that the response isn't sent until it is complete (i.e. it's buffered as with most frameworks/cms/etc.). Without addressing that [nothing would change if the same overall data is rendered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9361089/761202). You surely recognise that "use memcached, use pagination, use cache" is a broad answer - it's broad because the question has no details, it is best _not_ to answer such questions.